# SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq

I am configuring the rabbitmq ssl connection.
I already set the ssl file path on rabbitmq.conf. 
And I also get listening SSL log

```
=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:28 ===
node           : "BLIND"
home dir       : /root
config file(s) : /xxx/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_server-3.3.2/sbin/../etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
cookie hash    : Ux+c4k3F1Dveragf8mnmOQ==
log            : /xxx/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_server-3.3.2/log/xxx.log
sasl log       : /xxx/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_server-3.3.2/log/xxx-sasl.log
database dir   : /xxx/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_server-3.3.2/data/xxx

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:29 ===
Limiting to approx 924 file handles (829 sockets)

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:29 ===
Memory limit set to 6423MB of 16057MB total.

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:29 ===
Disk free limit set to 50MB

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:29 ===
msg_store_transient: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:29 ===
msg_store_persistent: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=WARNING REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:29 ===
msg_store_persistent: rebuilding indices from scratch

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:29 ===
started TCP Listener on 0.0.0.0:5671

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:29 ===
started MQTT TCP Listener on 0.0.0.0:1883

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:29 ===
started MQTT SSL Listener on 0.0.0.0:1884

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:30 ===
Management plugin started. Port: 15672

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:30 ===
Statistics database started.

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:18:30 ===
Server startup complete; 7 plugins started.
```

But when I connect the rabbitmq, then this message occurs.

> [root@BLIND sbin]# openssl s_client -connect localhost:1884 -tls1
>   CONNECTED(00000003) 32656:error:1409E0E5:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:536:

What is the wrong with this.

Comment: are you using centos?

Comment: yes. It is CentOS

Comment: erlang and rabbitmq versions?

Comment: rabbitmq version is 3.3.2, and erlang is maybe 5.9.1. When I write the command erl, then "Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:10:10] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]", this message occurs.

Comment: I need your help.. any other advice? - @Gabriele

Comment: Check this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/SSL3_WRITE_BYTES$3Assl$20handshake$20failure$3As3_pkt|sort:relevance/rabbitmq-users/FD2QtmbvsWY/6x3mcaAVp4oJ ! most likely you have to update your Erlang installation